# Methods of using mean function to parts of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, specifications, mean

*Hello,
I am learning with R and at this moment I use "iris" data which is default part of R. In iris data, I want to apply "mean" function to part of data frame.*

*My question does not concern anything complicated and 
it's because I am still quite new to R.*

**The data I am using are:**

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
```

---

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

What I want to do with it is apply mean function only e.g. to "setosa" in Species
and I want to calculate it just for "Sepal.Lenght".
The way I did it is (I actually apply it to "virginica" Species here, 
but I mean it just as example):

```
virgin<- iris[101:150,1]
virgin
```

and then

```
mean(virgin)
```

It gives me the correct mean but I think this method is kind of simple and is
probably not suited when you don't want to search through data.frame manually

**So my questions is how to do the same via other functions like
`apply` or others I do not know about.**

*You can also suggest some sources from where could I read more about it. 
It can be this page as well (I found only more advanced questions though).
If you want of course.*

**Thank you.**

Comment: And by the way, there is no need in `datasets`, `iris` is available within a clean session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really about how to subset a data frame.

Here is one way:

```
mean(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species=="virginica"])
[1] 6.588
```

You can rewrite this with less duplication by using the function `with()`:

```
mean(with(iris, Sepal.Length[Species=="virginica"]))
[1] 6.588
```

And another way:

```
mean(with(iris, iris[Species=="virginica", "Sepal.Length"]))
[1] 6.588
```

Comment: @Roland Yes, `subset()` is an option, but be careful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: This helped. I was surprised how simple is this solution. Thank you.